# Transfer data from Kafka store to a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to do something like this in Kafka:

1. Keep storing data in KStream/Ktable/Kafka-store
2. When my application receive a particular event/data, send ONLY specific set of data from the above store to a topic.

Can we do this in Kafka? I dont see using Kafka consumer alone going to help here as we cant start/pause consumer when a set of data has been consumed.

Comment: you can try creating kstream from above store based on filter you required so created stream create topic with desired data.

Comment: can you give some example

Answer (score 0):

Here is streams creation and join stream creation  configuration:-

```
CREATE STREAM Customer Profile WITH (
KAFKA_TOPIC = 'Customer Profile',
VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO',
KEY_FORMAT = 'AVRO'
```

);

```
CREATE STREAM Customer Buy WITH (
KAFKA_TOPIC = 'Customer Buy',
VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO',
KEY_FORMAT = 'AVRO'
```

);

Here I am creating a Kafka streams with another topics which is created from MYSQL tables

Once stream created we need to create another stream after apply joins and filter we need but joins in stream have condition that we can only apply joins with two streams.
here is the join ex:-

```
CREATE STREAM account_summary_by_category_by_month_by_accunt_no(
account_no int,
date_time timestamp,
category text,
category_description text,
amount float,
customer_id int,
FROM Customer_Profile  cp INNER JOIN Customer_Buy cb
WITHIN 7 DAYS
ON cp.id = cb.order_id;
```

You can apply all ksql function here like SQL for filter data

Comment: I didn't think you can have spaces in ksql entities or Kafka topics

Comment: ya i know but this is for understanding purpose